# What is causing LDOPE error when opening .hdf files?

Tags: modis

I get the following error when I try using LDOPE-1.7 on Linux (64 bit) with Modis QA data. The specific dataset resides in the LDOPE-1.7 directory.

```
bash-4.1$ ./unpack_sds_bits -of=ldopeQA.hdf -sds="BRDF Albedo Band Quality" -bit=0-3,4-7 MCD43A2.A2006153.h13v09.005.2008126030730.hdf
1 BRDF Albedo Band Quality

Processing input hdf file: MCD43A2.A2006153.h13v09.005.2008126030730.hdf
---------------------------------------------------------------
Cannot open input HDF file MCD43A2.A2006153.h13v09.005.2008126030730.hdf
Done!
```

Can anyone please point out where I am going wrong?